# Python: using re.sub to replace multiple substring multiple times

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to correct a text that has some very typical scanning errors (l mistaken for I and vice-versa). Basically I would like to have the replacement string in `re.sub` to depend on the number of times the 'I' is detected, something like that:

`re.sub("(\w+)(I+)(\w*)", "\g<1>l+\g<3>", "I am stiII here.")`

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you give examples of other situations you encountered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a function as the replacement string, as described in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub).  Your function can identify the mistake and create the best substitution based on that.

```
def replacement(match):
    if "I" in match.group(2):
        return match.group(1) + "l" * len(match.group(2)) + match.group(3)
    # Add additional cases here and as ORs in your regex

re.sub(r"(\w+)(II+)(\w*)", replacement, "I am stiII here.")
>>> I am still here.
```

(note that I modified your regex so the repeated Is would appear in one group.)

Comment: Yes; otherwise the first I gets swallowed by the \w+ in the first group.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that this mechanism existed. It's very useful to catch special cases without having to complicate the regular expression. I posted my final code in the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to replace only `I`s followed by or  preceded by another `I`:

```
print re.sub("(?<=I)I|I(?=I)", "l", "I am stiII here.")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you could do something like:

```
def replace_L(match):
    return match.group(0).replace(match.group(1),'l'*len(match.group(1)))

string_I_want=re.sub(r'\w+(I+)\w*',replace_L,'I am stiII here.')
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the answer proposed by DNS, I built something a bit more complicated to catch all the cases (or at least most of them), trying not to add too many errors:

```
def Irepl(matchobj):
    # Catch acronyms
    if matchobj.group(0).isupper():
        return matchobj.group(0)
    else:
        # Replace Group2 with 'l's
        return matchobj.group(1) + 'l'*len(matchobj.group(2)) + matchobj.group(3)


# Impossible to know if first letter is correct or not (possibly a name)
I_FOR_l_PATTERN = "([a-zA-HJ-Z]+?)(I+)(\w*)"
for line in lines:
    tmp_line = line.replace("l'", "I'").replace("'I", "'l").replace(" l ", " I ")
    tmp_line = re.sub("^l ", "I ", tmp_line)

    cor_line = re.sub(I_FOR_l_PATTERN, Irepl, tmp_line)

    # Loop to catch all errors in a word (iIIegaI for example)
    while cor_line != tmp_line:
        tmp_line = cor_line
        cor_line = re.sub(I_FOR_l_PATTERN, Irepl, tmp_line)
```

Hope this helps somebody else!